# File Directories

Tags: php, php-include

This might be a little silly question. Lets say I have a directory like this:

```
./index.php

./browse/blog.php
./browse/articles.php
./browse/categories.php

./includes/header.php
./includes/footer.php

./classes/init.php
./classes/core.php

./user/login.php
./user/register.php
```

My init.php and core.php need to be included in all my files e.g index.php and blog.php, articles.php and categories.php.

If I include core.php and init.php in header.php it works fine in index.php. But it doesnt work in articles.php, blog.php and so on basically anything that is in folders (browse or user)

header.php contains `include_once('../classes/core.php');` and `include_once('../classes/init.php');`

So my question is how would I be able to include a file in another file which is included in another file.

Let me rephrase. I want core.php and init.php to be included in header.php which is included in all other files. Like index.php and other files that are in folders.

Can I achieve this using relative file paths?

Comment: if you're doing includes in includes in .... you have to remember that relative paths are going to be relative to the MAIN file that started everything. If `index.php` includes `login` which includes `header`, then `../includes/header` in the login file is going to relative to index.php's path, not login's.

Comment: Also, I would replace `include` and `include_once` with `require_once`

Comment: @hermann, include is better for performance as long as you manage your includes.. as mentioned below to MueR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use relative paths, but you'd be much better off prepending `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to your file names to keep things simple.

Update regarding your comment:

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` provides you with the webroot path in a variable.

```
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include $doc_root . '/includes/whatever.php';
```

It will always provide an absolute path, regardless of which directory the calling script is in. It just makes life easy and means you don't have to figure out how many dots and slashes you need to get back to the file you want to include.

Comment: I dont really understand $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and how it works. How to get it included. I've read online but it didnt make much sense for me or probably wasnt explained properly. How do you work with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?

Answer (score 0):

header.php

```
include("../classes/init.php");
include("../classes/core.php");
```

login.php

```
include("../includes/header.php");
```

..and so on..

Comment: Change `include('../')` with `require_once '../'`.

Comment: @MueR, require_once is not as cool as you think, it is a wrapper to include that does checks first and therefore is actually slower than managing your includes yourself..

Comment: But to include something like database connect and session arrays with cookies would you not need require_once? Would include work?

Comment: Require_once prevents duplicate file loads, which are useful. The only time you should not use a require/include_once is in a loop. Duplicate  initialization of your code is nasty business.